# Can I deploy a Java Swing application as an enterprise application in Glassfish

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, glassfish, enterprise

I have a Swing application that runs as a desktop app but I would love to deploy it in Glassfish so that it would be accessible on a network. Is there any way of doing this? I was thinking of creating an enterprise application in Netbeans and including the apps jar file in it and then deploying but I am not sure if it would work.

Any solution/suggestion?

Comment: I think that the best solution will be deploy it as an Applet(with some modifications)

Answer (score 1):

[Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) will let you access your existing Swing app from a web page without any code changes. However, the app won't be ON the web page, but rather a download and auto-launch kind of thing.  If you've already done Swing development, then you may already be familiar with this since all of the Java tutorials have this.

For an example of how this works, see the [How to Use Password Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) tutorial, and click the Launch button on the web page.

As for the suggestion to convert your Swing app to an Applet, you might want to read [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) before changing your code.

Comment: What I am really looking at is a way for people on a LAN to access the app over the network ( a sort of client-server thing) or even through the internet. Thanks.